# a is undefined : openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2

I am trying to add kml to openlayers and i am getting error in firebug

```
  a is undefined: Line 92 openlayers.js
```

here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<title>OpenLayers Basic Single WMS Example</title>

<script src="OpenLayers-2.12/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map, layer;
    function init(){
        map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map' );
        layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
            "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
            {layers: 'basic'} );

        var kml =  new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "data/carmax.anand.kml",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    extractStyles: true, 
                    extractAttributes: true
                })
            })
        });
        map.addLayer(layer);
        map.addLayer(kml);
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<div id="map" class="smallmap" style="height:512px; width:512px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would go debugging into the line in your javascript that causes the error - try firebug or similar. I don't think its the cause of the error, but mind the invalid `comma` after `extractAttributes: true`.

Comment: Use `<script src="OpenLayers-2.12/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>`, this show which is the failing component.

Comment: @ chau : thank you for pointing invalid comma and yes I am using firebug, which is only giving me this scripting error.
@jorix : I used lib/openlayers.js and got this error : 

`node is undefined : Line 625`

Comment: @anand In which js file?

Comment: Is a error on lib/OpenLayers/Renderer/Elements.js, It can be an impropriety in the kml response, you can show a kml response from your server?

Comment: @jorix:  this error is in Util.js `node is undefined : Line 625 : Util.js`

Comment: This function is used in `Format\KML.js`, verify that the kml answer is correct.

Comment: I've checked KML in google earth, it is working properly. and also getting KML response in firebug. If I run the page without firebug then it is showing KML correctly,

Comment: I also tried using \OpenLayers-2.12\examples\kml-track.kml but again same error.

Comment: @anand You can post a kml resposnse from `data/carmax.anand.kml`?

Comment: @jorix : this is KML Response - https://www.dropbox.com/s/i8p8x08w21y3f0f/kml%20response.txt

Comment: @anand : There must be some confusion what you have posted is the content of `examples/kml/sundials.kml`. And using this response console does not warn of any error (FF+Firebug or chrome)

Answer (score 1):

You have wrongly defined height and width of your map div. Change it to the following:

```
<div id="map" class="smallmap" style="height:512px; width:512px"></div>
```

This should work for the wms layer, you have added.

Comment: It is still giving same error in firebug

Comment: As answered by xamamano, I have also tried with the local KML file. It is working. So there may be error in your kml file. You can check it through importing your KMl into Google Earth.

Comment: I can open my kml with Google earth without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, I've tried to read `examples/kml/sundials.kml` and no error. Can be a problem is the xml response.

NOTE: Remove the comma after `extractAttributes: true`, this causes problems with IE.

Use `http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/lib/OpenLayers.js` to see a more specific error.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else experiences same error I suggest adding maxExtent to OpenLayers.Map() options.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to expand upon your answer, because it was flagged up as low quality due to its length, please?